# How do I change title position to inside or over?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I downloaded the latest version of Fancybox, but for the life of me can't figure out how to get the title from outside to inside the box. I assume it is done through the helpers, but where do I put the code? Here's a link to my page, for what its worth. http://www.watercolorsplus.com/New/babyFootprints.html

I read elsewhere here that the code would look something like this:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    }
});
```

So would it go before the end of the body tag? In the head section? I must be missing something. I didn't think I had to change any of the CSS with the helpers.

Comment: That code is javascript. It would go into a .JS file that is referenced by your webpage, or inline inside some `<script type="text/javascript">` tags.

Comment: Right. OK, so I changed it from <script> to <script type="text/javascript">. I currently have it right before the closing body tag, but it still doesn't do the trick.

Comment: You actually have two scripts with `fancybox()`. First one is correct, because it is wrapped with `$(document).ready`. Second one is incorrect (not being wrapped), but still has `helpers` option. Move this second script code to the `$(document).ready` of the first one.

Comment: Just checked out your page - not you are already calling fancybox with  no arguments like this: `$(".fancybox").fancybox();` Try replacing that with the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place your fancybox custom script inside the `<head>` tag AND **after** you have loaded jQuery and fancybox js files like :

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title>title</title>
... other stuff, etc.
<link href="{path}/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="{path}/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="{path}/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        helpers: {
            title: {
                type: 'inside'
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
... other stuff maybe
</head>
```

Assuming that you have links with `class="fancybox"`.

And yes, if you are using the latest version of fancybox (v2.1.5 as today) you need the `helpers` API option to change the `title` position.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uej0v454/)**

Comment: Thanks all. Makes sense and is now working perfectly! I was missing the quotations after the class tag -- how I missed that I don't know! -- but more importantly didn't know where that helpers code was supposed to go -- inside the other as you and @Regent answered. I gotta get me that jQuery book from the library! thanks again, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 'helpers'. Just set the title to inside.

[Docs](http://fancybox.net/api)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        titlePosition:'inside'
    });  
});
```

Comment: Thanks to all. Unfortunately I am now away from my laptop so can't test the different options -- but I will! In regard to Mark's reply that I don't need "helpers", where exactly do I put that code? Forgive me, not well versed in JavaScript or jQuery yet -- does it go in the head section? Before the end body tag? Do I put it between script tags? Is my file structure too convoluted to where I have to be more specific in regard to file path (is ".fancybox" enough in the code?). Forgive me for too many questions, but I feel I've tried it all. Looking forward to getting back online to keep trying!

Comment: The OP seems to be using fancybox [v2.x](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) and not [v1.3.x](http://fancybox.net/)

Comment: @DaveHarrison - Use JFK's example below. My example is for the older version of fb.